# Gitignore folder name with wildcard

Tags: git, gitignore

How can I gitignore a folder with a name like this:
`myfolder*.pizza`

So the idea is that anything starting with `myfolder`, with anything in between as long as it ends with `.pizza` would be ignored.

Comment: `myfolder*.pizza` works just fine. Putting that in the `.gitignore` will ignore any files created under those paths. If I were to create a file inside `myfolder123.pizza` it would be ignored

Answer (score 1):

If a `myfolder*.pizza/` rule does not work, that should only mean the files in such a folder are already tracked.

In that case:

```bash
cd /path/to/repo
find . -name "myfolder*.pizza" -type d -exec git rm -r --cached {} ;
```